# Get maximazed form's height and width

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a form with several field controls and buttons below them. The requirement was to make this form maximized when opened. I did it by overriding form's run method and after super() I put `WinAPI::forceMaximizeWindow(element.hWnd());`

Field controls I have in one group and buttons in buttonGroup. These two groups are in one group which itself is in design node. What I want to do is to make these field controls and buttons to be aligned in the center of the maximized form, by properties or by code. I was thinking to get somehow the width and height of maximized form and to assign the left and top values to that group.

Any advice is appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of strange request but to get the form's width/height:

`element.design().widthValue();`

`element.design().heightValue();`

Example to set it:

`element.design().height(element.design().heightValue()/2);`

`element.design().width(element.design().widthValue()/2);`